# I made a custom page but Wordpress seems to strip any HTML I put in this page

Tags: pages

How can I avoid wordpress stripping HTML content from a custom PAGE?

Comment: what kind of html? are you using the visual editor or the html editor

Answer (score 1):

Use the **HTML Editor** *instead* of the WYSIWYG

[image: The Html Editor]

Comment: Yes. If you need to add custom HTML, then you should be using the HTML editor, rather than the Visual editor.

Comment: As well try not to go back and forth between visual and html. I just disable the visual since I write my own posts and when I have a guest written then I use a custom editor they submit into and it outputs the html. But most of my writers know html code

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, anytime you go to the WSYIWYG editor, it tends to strip out certain changes, so you need to stay in the HTML editor.

Comment: as @xLRDxREVENGEx said: Don't switch back and forth. If you want to do so: Save in between. Those are different "Sub-Programs" and don't "talk" to each other.